# Strict Standards error in joomla1.7

Tags: joomla, php, joomla1.7

I'm trying to create a web page using Joomla and XAMPP.

I'm getting **Strict Standards** in all parts of page... This is annoying.

> Strict Standards: Static function JDatabase::test() should not be abstract in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla17\libraries\joomla\database\database.php on line 350
>
> Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla17\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 394
>
> Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\Joomla17\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

One more thing i tried to change php.ini file.
I have two files in Joomla 1.7.
php INI-Devlolpment
php INI-Production

Whats difference between both?

I tried many thing to switch off strict standards:

> ; display_errors
>
> ;   Default Value: Off
>
> ;   Development Value: Off
>
> ;   Production Value: Off

also

> ; error_reporting
>
> ;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
>
> ;   Development Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
>
> ;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

also

> error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

also

> display_errors = Off

Still i'm getting these errors?

Please help me to solve this..
Thanks,
Shanmugam

Comment: @JonathonReinhart a more constructive thing to do would have been to comment on the answers explaining why they are wrong and allowing the answerers to amend/delete their answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display_errors = Off
```

should work. To find where it seted to On
It maybe

- php.ini
- httpd.conf
- .htaccess
- php code

To know what files used as php.ini you can use phpinfo(); and find path php.ini there

Comment: Thanks for your reply RiaD. but i could not get for your reply? you mean to say php.ini devlopment?

Comment: @shanmugam: added info how to find used php.ini

Comment: ok. but i have changed already from display_errors = On to display_errors = Off but still i'm getting those errors?

Comment: Now i got out from my error... First thing i was nit runnig Xampp in admin mode.. then i changed php.ini displa_errors=off...
I got out of my errors thanks thanks.... RiaD

Answer (score 7):

go to the file that cause error and change $this->_handler to self::$_handler

Comment: +1 for the solution helping to get rid of the error itself and not the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution to this problem is:

1. Go to "administrator" window
2. Under "global configuration" select "server"
3. In "server settings" set "Error Reporting" to "none" or "simple".

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop Apache and mysql services ( you may have to do it through SCM in Xampp control Panel)
2. open c:/xampp/php/php.ini
3. find Display_Error
4. there are two entries for Display_error one is with ; in start that is a comment second without ;
5. change Display_Error Off ( default it is On)
6. Start the services back.
7. http://localhost/joomla### and it should work.

**For those using Xampp 1.7.4, etc. the file is /opt/lamp/etc/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

run-C:\xampp\php\php.ini; open with Notepad, Ctrl+H; find:  e_strict, replaced:-empty-; replaced all; save; close.

Answer (score 0):

In my php.ini in the XAMPP lines below

```
532 ;http://php.net/display-errors
533 display_errors = On
```

to

```
532  ;http://php.net/display-errors
533  display_errors = Off
```

Stopped and then restarted Apache server and that make the annoying errors disappear.

Answer (score -1):

open `xampp/php/php.ini` with WordPad, then make `Ctrl+F` type `Display_Error` push find, there are two findings, yours is second. you'll see `display_errors` line with "on" next to it, just change it to off, `Ctrl+s` (you must save). should work

Answer (score -1):

Change file php/config.php

CHANGE LINE: `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

TO: `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Answer (score -1):

Joomla adminpanel:=

```
Go to "administrator"
Under "global configuration" select "server"
In "server settings" set "Error Reporting" to "none" or "simple".
```